# Skip rows with missing values in read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large csv which I need to read in. To make this fast and save RAM usage I am using read_csv and set the dtype of some columns to np.uint32.  The problem is that some rows have missing values and pandas uses a float to represent those.

1. Is it possible to simply skip rows with missing values? I know I could do this after reading in the whole file but this means I couldn't set the dtype until then and so would use too much RAM.
2. Is it possible to convert missing values to some other I choose during the reading of the data?

Comment: Would you consider preprocessing your data, such as 'grep -v ,, infile.csv > goodfile.csv`?  You might be able to more quickly eliminate "bad" lines that way. But it depends if empty values are invalid in *all* columns or just some.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Can you use 'grep' on Windows based machines?

Comment: @Merlin: Yes, I can.

Comment: @JohnZwinck   Not you the person, but rather the global you. (No longer a windows user. )  Do you think OP can?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I could preprocess but I am would prefer to have the processing all in one file if at all possible. Maybe Python could call grep and pipe the output to read_csv?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would be dainty if you could fill `NaN` with say `0` during read itself. Perhaps a feature request in Pandas's git-hub is in order...

## Using a converter function

However, for the time being, you can define your own function to do that and pass it to the `converters` argument in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
def conv(val):
    if val == np.nan:
        return 0 # or whatever else you want to represent your NaN with
    return val

df = pd.read_csv(file, converters={colWithNaN : conv}, dtypes=...)
```

Note that `converters` takes a `dict`, so you need to specify it for each column that has NaN to be dealt with. It can get a little tiresome if a lot of columns are affected. You can specify either column names or numbers as keys.

Also note that this might slow down your `read_csv` performance, depending on how the `converters` function is handled. Further, if you just have one column that needs NaNs handled during read, you can skip a proper function definition and use a `lambda` function instead:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, converters={colWithNaN : lambda x: 0 if x == np.nan else x}, dtypes=...)
```

---

## Reading in chunks

You could also read the file in small chunks that you stitch together to get your final output. You can do a bunch of things this way. Here is an illustrative example:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=1000)
for chunk in df:
    chunk.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True) # Dropping all rows with any NaN value
    chunk[colToConvert] = chunk[colToConvert].astype(np.uint32)
    result = result.append(chunk)
del df, chunk
```

Note that this method does not strictly duplicate data. There is a time when the data in `chunk` exists twice, right after the `result.append` statement, but only `chunksize` rows are repeated, which is a fair bargain. This method may also work out to be faster than by using a converter function.

Comment: I guess that depends if the table has any NaN  in the input that are wanted.

Comment: @Jasen, Well, this is representative pseudo code. It is not meant as a drop in replacement. Perhaps the data being read is empty, so the `if` statement should be changed to `if val is None:`. Perhaps it has some other representation...

Comment: Thank you. This answers question 2. Can this method be used to answer question 1.  somehow?

Comment: I don't think you can use `pandas.read_csv` in a way that will skip a row with a missing value. If all values in a row are missing, there is a `skip_blank_lines` kwag that is set to `True` by default so nothing more you can do about that. Did you think of reading the file in chunks, processing it and stitching them back together? I can edit my answer to include that method as well.

Comment: If you feel your questions have been answered, please mark as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature in Pandas that does that.  You can implement it in regular Python like this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

def filter_records(records):
    """Given an iterable of dicts, converts values to int.
    Discards any record which has an empty field."""

    for record in records:
        for k, v in record.iteritems():
            if v == '':
                break
            record[k] = int(v)
        else: # this executes whenever break did not
            yield record

with open('t.csv') as infile:
    records = csv.DictReader(infile)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(filter_records(records))
```

Pandas uses the `csv` module internally anyway.  If the performance of the above turns out to be a problem, you could probably speed it up with Cython (which Pandas also uses).

Comment: This seems to create two copies of the input in RAM? The first copy 'records' has the entire file before type conversion. It's exactly this that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Probably `pandas.read_csv` is also prone to data duplication. At least it was, if you read [this blog][1] by Wes McKinny the creator of pandas. But note that the blog was written in October 2012, and like the disclaimer on the blog says, it has been some time, and most of that information is outdated. I do not know what the modern, shiny `read_csv` can in terms of memory management do.

  [1]: http://wesmckinney.com/blog/a-new-high-performance-memory-efficient-file-parser-engine-for-pandas/

Answer (score -3):

If you show some data, SO ppl could help.

```
pd.read_csv('FILE', keep_default_na=False)
```

For starters try these:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

```
na_values : str or list-like or dict, default None
Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA values. By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘nan’.

keep_default_na : bool, default True
If na_values are specified and keep_default_na is False the default NaN values are overridden, otherwise they’re appended to.

na_filter : boolean, default True
    Detect missing value markers (empty strings and the value of na_values). In data without any NAs, passing na_filter=False can improve the performance of reading a large file
```