# Drop Na values in the reading data function

Tags: pandas

I am taking an online course on Data Science py Python.

One thing I'm curious is that can we drop NAN values when we load the data by read_csv with pandas imported?

If can, how can we specified that variables in read_csv?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818609/skip-rows-with-missing-values-in-read-csv

Answer (score 0):

According to the [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation, there's no option to drop rows with NA values while reading the file; you'll need to do that afterwards with `dropna`.