# Pandas - how to drop rows containing fewer fields than header

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Pandas correctly errors out the rows which contain more fields than the header in a csv, however it adds `NaN` to rows containing lesser fields even if there is no trailing `,` indicating an empty field.

My csv:

```
id,name,pin,city
1,abc,123,SJ
2,xyz,789
3,pqr,456,AL
4,qwe,345,
```

When I try to read this via pandas:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> a = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
>>> a
   id name  pin city
0   1  abc  123   SJ
1   2  xyz  789  NaN
2   3  pqr  456   AL
3   4  qwe  345  NaN
>>>
```

Here row 4 is read with `NaN` in city value, which is correct since last `,` indicates an empty field. But line 2 should error out/not read into the dataframe. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: A similar question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818609/skip-rows-with-missing-values-in-read-csv/38819282

Answer (score 1):

You can preprocessing values for find rows with not equal length and passes to parameter `skiprows` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
out = []
with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    head = next(reader)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if len(row) != len(head):
            out.append(i)
print (out)
[1]

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows=np.array(out) + 1)
print(df)
   id name  pin city
0   1  abc  123   SJ
1   3  pqr  456   AL
2   4  qwe  345  NaN
```

Comment: I would use the csv itself to then process my data instead of pandas if this is the last solution

Comment: @MohitC - added another solution.

Comment: I don't see it? Your solution still uses csv module to pre process. Doubles my complexity

Comment: @MohitC It is best what I find, but be free wait for another answers.