# Pandas: read_csv reading large csv file with no NaNs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset in `.csv` file format, with around 60 GB of data containing more than 60% of the data is missing in some columns and rows, Since Its not possible to read such a huge file directly into `jupyter notebook`, I want to read only **specific columns** and **only non-null rows** into jupyter notebook using `pandas.read_csv`.
How can this be done?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: anything that reduces the processing steps of [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) will help, some example: `pandas.read_csv( low_memory=True, memory_map=True, usecols = ['col1','col2'], na_filter=True,  skip_blank_lines=True, iterator=True, chunksize=10000,error_bad_lines=False )`  includes @naga-kiran suggestion to iterating in chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the CSV file chunk by chunk and retain the rows which you want to have

```
iter_csv = pd.read_csv('sample.csv',, usecols = ['col1','col2'] iterator=True, chunksize=10000,error_bad_lines=False)
data = pd.concat ([chunk.dropna(how='all') for chunk in iter_csv] )
```

Answer (score 2):

Check following [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61651742/7775043) in a previous post.

The pandas documentation suggest you can read a csv file selecting only the columns which you want to read.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('some_data.csv', usecols = ['col1','col2'], low_memory = True)
```

Comment: Thanks!  How about reading 60 GB of data.. actually important thing is to ignore the rows that contain NaNs and read only non-null rows...

Comment: No problem. So you would like to a have a function which indicates if the column includes NA and then drop it for the import?

Comment: As I am currently not able to verify this for sure, I can refer you to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38819282/7775043). During the day I can check this, but maybe this already helps you to find a solution.