# Take time points, and make labels against datetime object to correlate for things around points

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use the usual times I take medication (so + 4 hours on top of that) and fill in a data frame with a label, of being 2,1 or 0, for when I am on this medication, or for the hour after the medication as 2 for just being off of the medication.

As an example of the dataframe I am trying to add this column too,

```
<bound method NDFrame.to_clipboard of                           id  sentiment  magnitude  angry  disgusted  fearful  \
created                                                                         
2020-05-21 12:00:00     23.0  -0.033333        0.5    NaN        NaN      NaN   
2020-05-21 12:15:00      NaN        NaN        NaN    NaN        NaN      NaN   
2020-05-21 12:30:00      NaN        NaN        NaN    NaN        NaN      NaN   
2020-05-21 12:45:00      NaN        NaN        NaN    NaN        NaN      NaN   
2020-05-21 13:00:00      NaN        NaN        NaN    NaN        NaN      NaN   
...                      ...        ...        ...    ...        ...      ...   
2021-04-20 00:45:00      NaN        NaN        NaN    NaN        NaN      NaN   
2021-04-20 01:00:00      NaN        NaN        NaN    NaN        NaN      NaN   
2021-04-20 01:15:00      NaN        NaN        NaN    NaN        NaN      NaN   
2021-04-20 01:30:00      NaN        NaN        NaN    NaN        NaN      NaN   
2021-04-20 01:45:00  46022.0  -1.000000        1.0    NaN        NaN      NaN   

                     happy  neutral  sad  surprised  
created                                              
2020-05-21 12:00:00    NaN      NaN  NaN        NaN  
2020-05-21 12:15:00    NaN      NaN  NaN        NaN  
2020-05-21 12:30:00    NaN      NaN  NaN        NaN  
2020-05-21 12:45:00    NaN      NaN  NaN        NaN  
2020-05-21 13:00:00    NaN      NaN  NaN        NaN  
...                    ...      ...  ...        ...  
2021-04-20 00:45:00    NaN      NaN  NaN        NaN  
2021-04-20 01:00:00    NaN      NaN  NaN        NaN  
2021-04-20 01:15:00    NaN      NaN  NaN        NaN  
2021-04-20 01:30:00    NaN      NaN  NaN        NaN  
2021-04-20 01:45:00    NaN      NaN  NaN        NaN  

[32024 rows x 10 columns]>
```

And the data for the timestamps for when i usually take my medication,

```
['09:00 AM', '12:00 PM', '03:00 PM']
```

How would I use those time stamps to get this sort of column information?

#### Update

So, trying to build upon the question, How would I make sure it only adds medication against places where there is data available, and making sure that the after medication timing  of one hour is applied correctly!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`np.select()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to choose the appropriate label for a given condition.

First `dropna()` if all values after `created` are null (`subset=df.columns[1:]`). You can change the `subset` depending on your needs (e.g., `subset=['id']` if rows should be dropped just for having a null `id`).

Then generate `datetime` arrays for taken-, active-, and after-medication periods based on the `duration` of the medication. Check whether the `created` times match any of the times in `active` (label 1) or `after` (label 2), otherwise default to 0.

```py
# drop rows that are empty except for column 0 (i.e., except for df.created)
df.dropna(subset=df.columns[1:], inplace=True)

# convert times to datetime
df.created = pd.to_datetime(df.created)
taken = pd.to_datetime(['09:00:00', '12:00:00', '15:00:00'])

# generate time arrays
duration = 2 # hours
active = np.array([(taken + pd.Timedelta(f'{h}H')).time for h in range(duration)]).ravel()
after = (taken + pd.Timedelta(f'{duration}H')).time

# define boolean masks by label
conditions = {
    1: df.created.dt.floor('H').dt.time.isin(active),
    2: df.created.dt.floor('H').dt.time.isin(after),
}

# create medication column with np.select()
df['medication'] = np.select(conditions.values(), conditions.keys(), default=0)
```

Here is the output with some slightly modified data that better demonstrate the `active` / `after` / `nan` scenarios:

```
               created       id  sentiment  magnitude  medication
0  2020-05-21 12:00:00     23.0  -0.033333        0.5           1
3  2020-05-21 12:45:00     39.0  -0.500000        0.5           1
4  2020-05-21 13:00:00     90.0  -0.500000        0.5           1
5  2020-05-21 13:15:00    100.0  -0.033333        0.1           1
9  2020-05-21 14:15:00   1000.0   0.033333        0.5           2
10 2020-05-21 14:30:00      3.0   0.001000        1.0           2
17 2021-04-20 01:00:00  46022.0  -1.000000        1.0           0
20 2021-04-20 01:45:00  46022.0  -1.000000        1.0           0
```

Comment: With the medication, say there was a active time of 4 hours, what would that look like (so the medication time if 12, then the active time is for 4 hours after that, so all values are 1 when it is active, then for one hour after that there is value 2)

Comment: @LeCoda In that case how would overlaps like 4PM be handled? It would be label 2 based on the 12PM med but label 1 based on the 3PM med.

Comment: @LeCode I've updated the code to handle a configurable `duration` of active hours and to ignore null rows. I've set `duration=2` for now since it's not clear how overlaps would be handled.

Comment: Almost perfect, I just didn't want the data frame to get bigger by adding rows when it wasn't needed - can it just not populate the rows without any other inputs?

Comment: @LeCoda Ahh ok, in that case we can use the original version without the `isnull()` mask.  Instead use `dropna()` with `subset=df.columns[1:]` to drop all rows that are empty except for `df.created`.

Comment: Awesome - Only thought on this, can we avoid creating new rows altogether, instead of creating than destroying them?

Comment: @LeCoda where will your real data come from? a csv file? it looks like [there are some workarounds to skip null rows during `read_csv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38819282/13138364), but in my opinion it's not really necessary